# How to change the access tier for all files within an Azure storage account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

How can I change the access tier to "archive" for all files within an Azure Storage account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the access tier for each file individually.  Here's a powershell script that will do that using the [Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest):

https://gist.github.com/MattRuwe/f1a4e09a55fed89a7857ec00ec772028

```perl
$connectionString = "<ConnectionString>"
$containerName = "<ContainerName>"

$hotAccessTierFiles = az storage blob list --connection-string $connectionString --container-name $containerName --query "[?properties.blobTier=='Hot'].name" --num-results *

$hotAccessTierFilesObject = $hotAccessTierFiles | ConvertFrom-Json

$hotAccessTierFilesObject | % { az storage blob set-tier --connection-string $connectionString --container-name $containerName --name $_ --tier "Archive" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution that pages and I can store in source control without a connection string.

```
$resourceGroup = "<resourceGroup>"
$storageAccount = "<storageAccount>"
$containerName = "<containerName>"

$connectionString = az storage account show-connection-string --name $storageAccount --out tsv

$response =(az storage blob list --container-name $containerName --connection-string $connectionString --num-results 10 --show-next-marker) | ConvertFrom-Json
$next_token = $response.nextMarker 

while ($next_token -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($file in $response)
    {           
        if ($file.properties.contentLength -gt 0 -and $file.properties.blobTier -eq 'Hot')
        {           
            Write-Host "$($file.name):$($file.properties.contentLength)"
            az storage blob set-tier --connection-string $connectionString --container-name $containerName --name $file.name --tier "Archive" 
        }               
    }
    $response =(az storage blob list --container-name $containerName --connection-string $connectionString --num-results 10 --marker $next_token --show-next-marker) | ConvertFrom-Json
    $next_token = $response.nextMarker 
}
```